# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnspython': Trying to import installed packages ('dnspython','py3dns')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Package installed but can't be imported : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named. There's a chance I do not use the module right, Idk (tried from module import *, import module and from module import module). The package I'd like to install is py3dns/ dnspython - I don't care which of them, just trying to make [validate_email('example@example.com',check_mx=True)] work, and in the validate_email's instruction they wrote "check_mx" need pyDNS. I understood pyDNS is not supported anymore in python 3.

Answer (score 1):

`validate_email` does [`import DNS`](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/blob/eaf2668a84b6fb40d9138056b63bc74c6d718d95/validate_email.py#L32) which means it only works with `PyDNS`, not `dnspython`.

Answer (score 0):

install py3DNS and validate_email with:

```
sudo -H pip install py3dns validate_email
```

or on Windows just use admin cmd prompt:

```
pip install py3dns validate_email
```

then you can run your code normally

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com', verify=True)
```

Comment: I get this: 
Exception: For check the mx records or check if the email exists you must have installed pyDNS python package